# How to set dark theme in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

I seen on the JetBrains site (in a post about youtrack 5 EAP) that is possible to set a dark theme to YouTrack, similar to the IntelliJ' Darcula Theme.

How & where can I activate it on YouTrack ? And its follow the colors of Darcula theme ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2019.3 you can find it by clicking on your profile image in top right corner of the screen:

[image: youtrack dark theme location]

Answer (score 8):

It's only availalbe for agile board body (not header). The control for enabling it is near from where you switch board card details mode -- right buttons groups below the search bar.
Update: in YouTrack 2018.3 the dark theme is available on single issue screen view, soon coming to issue list.

Comment: I see. I'm a little bit disappointed ; I hoped a YouTrack' Darcula theme as in IDEA. Too bad that it's not exist...

Comment: I want a dark theme, too

Comment: The dark theme has been added to full issue screen, issue list will follow.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has made a CSS page-load script for it, for a browser plugin to apply. Like Stylist in chrome. That'll be precisely what I do next, in the meantime. Suggest others do same :)